# How to read a txt file in R which indicates page number and paragraphs in each page

Tags: r

I have read a .txt file using `readLines()` in R. I have not given line numbers-(ie.Display line numbers) in the txt file.
The txt file is in this form.

```
        page1:
       paragraph1:Banks were early adopters, but now the range of applications 
            and organizations using predictive analytics successfully have multiplied. Direct marketing and sales.
     Leads coming in from a company’s website can be scored to determine the probability of a 
                            sale and to set the proper follow-up priority. 
paragraph2: Campaigns can be targeted to the candidates most 
                        likely to respond. Customer relationships.Customer characteristics and behavior are strongly 
                        predictive of attrition (e.g., mobile phone contracts and credit cards). Attrition or “churn” 
                    models help companies set strategies to reduce churn rates via communications and special offers. 
                Pricing optimization. With sufficient data, the relationship between demand and price can be modeled for 
            any product and then used to determine the best pricing strategy.
```

Similarly page2 in the .txt file have paragraphs.

But i couldn't differentiate between pages and paragraph, since .txt file doesn't differentiate pages.  Is there any way or suggestion to indicate pages and paragraph in R.

The answer given by **Edward Carney** is just right for this. But if I'm not using "paragraph(No.)" how to identify the paragraph using tab/space?

Comment: "page number" is based on the number of lines per page, font size, and presence of `^L` (newline) in the source. The only thing I can think of for paragraphs (which may span pages) would be a double line feed (consecutive `\n`). Do you have any other clear way of delineating one from the other?

Comment: `grep('^\t', x)` for tab. The `^` character insures that this will only "see" tabs at the beginnings of lines. You can use the same idea for space characters, but spaces might be problematic for other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method uses the `stripWhitespace` function from the `tm` library, but, other than that, it's basic R.

First, read in the text and locate the `page#:` lines using `grep`.

```
x <- readLines('text2.txt')
page_locs <- grep('page\\d:', x)
# add an element with the last line of the text plus 1
page_locs[length(page_locs)+1] <- length(x) + 1
# strip out the whitespace
x <- stripWhitespace(x)
# break the text into a list of pages, eliminating the `page#:` lines.
pages <- list()
# grab each page's lines into successive list elements
for (i in 1:(length(page_locs)-1)) {
  pages[[i]] <- x[(page_locs[i]+1):(page_locs[i+1]-1)]
}
```

Then, process each page into a list of paragraphs for each page.

```
for (i in 1:length(pages)) {
    # get the locations for the paragraphs
    para_locs <- grep('paragraph\\d:', pages[[i]])
    # add an end element
    para_locs[length(para_locs) + 1] <- length(pages[[i]]) + 1
    # delete the paragraph marker
    curr_page <- gsub('paragraph\\d:','',pages[[i]])
    curr_paras <- list()
    # step through the paragraphs in each page
    for (j in 1:(length(para_locs)-1)) {
        # collapse the vectors for each paragraph
        curr_paras[[j]] <- paste(curr_page[para_locs[j]:(para_locs[j+1]-1)], collapse='')
        # delete leading spaces for each paragraph if desired
        curr_paras[[j]] <- gsub('^ ','',curr_paras[[j]])
    }
    # store the list of paragraphs back into the pages list
    pages[[i]] <- curr_paras
}
```

You might need some additional clean up depending on your text.